# What is the policy about spoilers here?

Tags: support, spoilers

I recently asked my first question here. In my [first version](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/78461/1), I used a spoiler block to hide most of the text. Soon after, a mod passed by and [edited the spoiler block away](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/78461/2), leaving all the text visible.

Later, I got downvoted for "spoilers", but it is not given if spoilers in the title or in the body. After I posted my comment, explaining to the user why I thought I did not spoil anything in the title, and that the body got edited, I have received no further explanation.

Today I then notice [a](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78834/33910) few [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78826/33910) were spoiler blocks are extensively used and/or added at the request of other users.

Can someone help me understand what is the policy here about spoiler blocks? When/how should they be used?

---

Note: I don't want anyone to pile on the downvoter or the mod, I understand why the downvoter behaved that way (even if it appears to be against [community consensus](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2666/33910)), and I understand that the mod wanted to help me with my first question. I am here to ask you about site policies, not to crusade against this or that user.

Comment: Also related: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/are-we-overusing-the-spoiler-markup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current *consensus* is that spoilers should not be in **titles** only.

I'm not aware of any specific consensus about spoilers in question text **unless** the bulk of the question becomes unreadable because it mostly consists of spoilers.

See?

[image]

I suspect that *this* is the reason the mod removed the spoilers. One could argue that the mod could have made a more elaborate job of it but, as I said, the current guidelies/consensus is regarding **titles** only.

---

> Later, I got downvoted for "spoilers",

You might assume that but unless the voter gave a reason in comments, you don't **know** that.

Comment: <You might assume that but unless the voter gave a reason in comments, you don't know that.> they did (and later deleted the comment)

Comment: Well, there you are. They aren't **supposed** to DV for spoilers but we can't stop them.

Comment: I know, that's why I added the note asking not to chase the user around about this.